# Create function in R to find coupon rate for bond

Tags: r, algorithm

So far, I have written the following function:

```
c_rate <- function (bond_value, par, ttm, y) {

   t <- seq(1, ttm, 1)

  pv_factor <- 1 / (1 + y)^t

 cr <- (bond_value - par / (1+y)^t) / (par*sum(pv_factor))

 cr
 }
```

however, this yields multiple results.

How can i update the function to only yield one the final index only?

Comment: In the final line. Replace t with ttm to calculate cr. No need to use a sequence if you want the final index only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to raise `(1+y)^t` to the power of `ttm` instead:

```
cr <- (bond_value - par / (1+y)^ttm) / (par*sum(pv_factor))
```